# Unexpected arguments while saving contents

Tags: python, django

I am a newby in django . I tried to make an feedback app but I am not able to save the contents . It show:

> unexpected argument "name"

my code is

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def positive(request):
    if(request.method=="POST"):
        confirm_message = " "
        context = {'confirm_message': confirm_message}
        name = request.POST['name']
        suggest = request.POST['suggest']
        improve = request.POST['improve']
        posi = positive(name=name , suggest=suggest , improve=improve)
        posi.save()
        confirm_message = "Thanks for the message . We Will get right back to you."
        context = {'confirm_message': confirm_message,} 
        return render(request,'positive.html',context)

    else:
        return render(request,'positive.html')



def negative(request):
    if(request.method=="POST"):
        confirm_message = " "
        context = {'confirm_message': confirm_message}
        name = request.POST['name']
        upset = request.POST['upset']
        change = request.POST['change']
        negi = negative(name=name , upset=upset , change=change)
        negi.save()
        confirm_message = "Thanks for the message . We Will get right back to you."
        context = {'confirm_message': confirm_message,} 
        return render(request,'negative.html',context)

    else:
        return render(request,'negative.html')
```

**models.py**

```
class positive(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None)
    suggest = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    improve = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'Name : %s suggest:   %s \nimprove:   %s  ' % (self.name,self.suggest,self.improve)


class negative(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None)
    upset = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    change = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'Name : %s upset:   %s \nchange:   %s  ' % (self.name,self.upset,self.change)
```

Comment: change your model names, they should be uppercase letters for classes, I think there is a clash between your views and models when calling because of your similar naming conventions...

Comment: Please, post full exception traceback. Also, read python tutorial and PEP-8. Your code is totally unpythonic. Class names should start with uppercase letters. There's no need to wrap `if` conditions in parens. There's no need to set `confirm_message` in the context dictionary twice.

Comment: your class name and function name should not be same, and class name should like `Positive` and `Negative`